# How to control for common method bias?

Tags: factor-analysis, interaction, structural-equation-modeling

I am doing CFA to test for common method bias using an unmeasured latent construct method. The average common variance I am getting from the common factor is about 31% which is high (as should be less than 25%).

I checked for differences in p-values of the trait loadings (between CFA model with ULC and without ULC) and p-values become insignificant for only one scale.

What can I do to control the effect of common method variance statistically in this case?

I am doing a moderation analysis and I have 6 variables

Comment: Try looking into the work of Terence (T. J. G.) Tracey for info on a method of partialing out the first unrotated
factor as a "general factor" attributable to social desirability or common method bias.

Answer (score 1):

You might also wanted to try using a marker variable (Williams, Hartman, & Cavazotte (2010). Method Variance and Marker Variables: A Review and Comprehensive Marker Technique. the Organizational Research Methods) which is simply explained in this youtube.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7zZCBlRXog&lc=5D_7EzRSjHAjwrJJdM0epb8dEiSNe_zaTs0AopwzZ1s&lch=email_reply&feature=em-comment_reply_received